# What is the preferred way to include error messages in C++?

Tags: c++, error-handling, coding-style

Which of the following alternatives would be preferred?

1. Include the error message within code wherever needed:

   ```
   cout << "I am an error message!" <<endl;
   exit(-1);
   ```
2. Define the error messages in a separate header file:

   ```
   #include "ErrorMessages.h"
   cout << ERRORMESSAGE_1 <<endl;
   exit(-1);
   ```
3. Create a function that contains the error messages.

Also is it common to include unique error IDs as part of these messages?

Comment: The first way is not very localization-friendly.

Comment: ...Aaaaaaand, error messages go to `cerr`, not to `cout`.

Comment: ...or 4. Load the messages from external file.

Comment: It's nice to remember that some libraries offers features that may change one's perspective on this. For example, Qt (which is mainly for C++) has its own translation system with QObject::tr() + the whole translation system with QtLinguist which makes the idea of error messages in one place quite unnecessary (repetitions are easily handled with global replace Ctrl+Shift+R in Qt Creator). So I suggest one should always learn the translation features of one's development environment before making this decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is all a matter of preference with both benefits and downfalls.

Hard-coding string literals at the site of the error may be harder to maintain but it also is easier to read in my honest opinion.

for example

```
cout << "You were unable to login. "
     << "Please check you're user name and password and try again"
     << endl;
```

shows intent a lot better than

```
cout << LOGIN_CREDENTIALS_ERROR << endl;
```

However, the plus sides of not hard-coding the message (both `2` and `3`):

```
//Foo.cpp:
cout << DIVIDE_BY_ZERO_ERROR << endl;

//Bar.cpp
cout << DIVIDE_BY_ZERO_ERROR << endl;

// If you want to change DIVIDE_BY_ZERO_ERROR text you only have to do it once
//ErrorMessages.h (Ops grammar needs correcting)
const std:string DIVIDE_BY_ZERO_ERROR = "Dont not divide by zero";
```

Also, if the error messages are subject to change:

```
// ErrorMessages.h
#ifdef LOCALIZATION_EN
const std:string FRIENDLY_ERROR = "Hello, you are doing something wrong";
#elseif LOCALIZATION_FR
const std:string FRIENDLY_ERROR = "Bonjour, ...";
...
```

OR

```
// ErrorMessages.h
#ifdef DEBUG
const std:string SOME_ERROR = "More detailed error information for developers"
#else
const std:string SOME_ERROR = "Human friendly error message"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon if you have localization requirements for your application. If you do, you want all your strings in one place, including error messages. If you don't have requirements like that, I prefer to put the messages inline (your first example). That way, if I want to find the code that's complaining, I can just grep the message.